# SciChart: Working with Zooming module is not working

Tags: scichart, scichart.js

I am using SciChart Library for showing Graphs.

I want to know, how can I use **MouseWheelZoomModifier** module of SciChart library in my pure HTML & CSS based website.

I know there is a documentation available related to React but I am not using it in my Website.

I have written the following Code:

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <!-- Include SciChart.js -->
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/scichart@2.1.2290/_wasm/scichart.browser.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <title>Hello, SciChart.js world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, SciChart.js world!</h1>
    <!-- Create the Div to host the SciChartSurface -->
    <div id="scichart-root" style="width: 800px; height: 600px;"></div>
    <!-- The JavaScript to create a SciChartSurface -->
    <script>
      async function initSciChart() {
        // In order to load data file from the CDN we need to set dataUrl
        SciChart.SciChartSurface.configure({
          dataUrl: `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/scichart@${SciChart.libraryVersion}/_wasm/scichart2d.data`,
          wasmUrl: `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/scichart@${SciChart.libraryVersion}/_wasm/scichart2d.wasm`
        });
        // Create a SciChartSurface inside the div with id 'scichart-root'
        const {
          sciChartSurface,
          wasmContext
        } = await SciChart.SciChartSurface.create("scichart-root");

        // Add an X and a Y Axis
        const xAxis = new SciChart.NumericAxis(wasmContext);
        sciChartSurface.xAxes.add(xAxis);
        const yAxis = new SciChart.NumericAxis(wasmContext);
        sciChartSurface.yAxes.add(yAxis);
        
         // Create 100 dataseries, each with 10k points
        for (let seriesCount = 0; seriesCount < 100; seriesCount++) {       
            const xyDataSeries = new SciChart.XyDataSeries(wasmContext);
            const opacity = (1 - ((seriesCount / 120))).toFixed(2);
            // Populate with some data
            for(let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                xyDataSeries.append(i, Math.sin(i* 0.01) * Math.exp(i*(0.00001*(seriesCount+1))));
            }
            // Add and create a line series with this data to the chart
            // Create a line series       
            const lineSeries = new SciChart.FastLineRenderableSeries(wasmContext, {
                dataSeries: xyDataSeries,
                stroke: `rgba(176,196,222,${opacity})`,
                strokeThickness:2
            });
            sciChartSurface.renderableSeries.add(lineSeries);
        }
        
        // BELOW ONE NOT WORKING
        // Add zoom, pan behaviours to the chart. Mousewheel zoom, panning and double-click to
        // zoom to fit
        const mouseWheelZoomModifier = new MouseWheelZoomModifier();
        const zoomPanModifier = new ZoomPanModifier();   
        const rubberBandZoomModifier = new RubberBandXyZoomModifier();
        const zoomExtentsModifier = new ZoomExtentsModifier();   
        sciChartSurface.chartModifiers.add(zoomExtentsModifier);
        sciChartSurface.chartModifiers.add(zoomPanModifier);
        sciChartSurface.chartModifiers.add(rubberBandZoomModifier);
        sciChartSurface.chartModifiers.add(mouseWheelZoomModifier);   
        const inputEnablePan = document.getElementById("enable-pan");
        const inputEnableZoom = document.getElementById("enable-zoom");
        const inputEnableZoomToFit = document.getElementById("enable-zoom-to-fit");
        const inputEnableMouseWheel = document.getElementById("enable-mouse-wheel-zoom");
        inputEnablePan.addEventListener("input", (event) => {
            zoomPanModifier.isEnabled = inputEnablePan.checked;
            rubberBandZoomModifier.isEnabled = !inputEnablePan.checked;
            inputEnableZoom.checked = !inputEnablePan.checked;       
            console.log(`Enabling Drag to Pan. Status: rubberBand checkbox ${inputEnableZoom.checked}, rubberBand ${rubberBandZoomModifier.isEnabled}, zoomPan checkbox ${inputEnablePan.isEnabled}, zoomPan ${zoomPanModifier.isEnabled} `);
        });
        inputEnableZoom.addEventListener("input", (event) => {
            rubberBandZoomModifier.isEnabled = inputEnableZoom.checked;
            zoomPanModifier.isEnabled = !inputEnableZoom.checked;
            inputEnablePan.checked = !inputEnableZoom.checked;
            console.log(`Enabling Drag to Zoom. Status: rubberBand checkbox ${inputEnableZoom.checked}, rubberBand ${rubberBandZoomModifier.isEnabled}, zoomPan checkbox ${inputEnablePan.isEnabled}, zoomPan ${zoomPanModifier.isEnabled} `);
        });
        inputEnableZoomToFit.addEventListener("input", (event) => {
            zoomExtentsModifier.isEnabled = inputEnableZoomToFit.checked;
            console.log("Enabling zoom extents");
        });
        inputEnableMouseWheel.addEventListener("input", (event) => {
            mouseWheelZoomModifier.isEnabled = inputEnableMouseWheel.checked;
            console.log("Enabling Mousewheel zoom");
        });
        
      }
      initSciChart();
    
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Output:**
[image]

The MouseWheelZoomModifier is actually the module that is import using import keyword in React tutorial but how can I use it in HTML & CSS based Web Page.

Kindly Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using [SciChart's Browser module](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/js/current/Tutorial%2001%20-%20Including%20SciChart.js%20in%20an%20HTML%20Page.html) (where the code is served from CDN and JS rather than npm/webpack) you need to use a slightly different way to declare objects in code.

Note the [Tutorial for setting up SciChart.js with browser module](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/js/current/Tutorial%2001%20-%20Including%20SciChart.js%20in%20an%20HTML%20Page.html) says

> Notice every API call is prefixed by `SciChart.` when using the browser bundle. This is the global namespace for all SciChart apis, functions and types.

Once you have added the script to include scichart.js (and version)

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/scichart@2.1.2290/_wasm/scichart.browser.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

You must now tell SciChart where to load the wasm files from. The easiest way to do this is to call [SciChartSurface.useWasmFromCDN()](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/js/current/webframe.html#SciChartSurface.create.html);

```
SciChart.SciChartSurface.useWasmFromCDN();
```

Next, when not using npm/webpack every type in the SciChart library is now prepended with the global variable `SciChart.`

For example in our npm/webpack docs this code:

```
const mouseWheelZoomModifier = new MouseWheelZoomModifier();
sciChartSurface.chartModifiers.add(mouseWheelZoomModifier);
```

must become this

```
const mouseWheelZoomModifier = new SciChart.MouseWheelZoomModifier();
sciChartSurface.chartModifiers.add(mouseWheelZoomModifier);
```

Alternatively you can pre-declare these types as follows:

```
// When using SciChart from CDN / browser bundle, there are no imports
// so either prepend every variable by global namespace SciChart.
// or use code like this to get the types out
const {
    MouseWheelZoomModifier,
    SciChartSurface,
    NumericAxis
} = SciChart;

// static func. Call once. load wasm from CDN 
SciChartSurface.useWasmFromCDN(); 

// Create a SciChartSurface in <div id="div-id"/>
const { sciChartSurface, wasmContext } = SciChartSurface.create("div-id");

// Add x,y axis 
sciChartSurface.xAxes.add(new NumericAxis(wasmContext)); 
sciChartSurface.yAxes.add(new NumericAxis(wasmContext)); 

// Add modifiers for zooming, panning
const mouseWheelZoomModifier = new MouseWheelZoomModifier();
sciChartSurface.chartModifiers.add(mouseWheelZoomModifier);
```

Try that and see if it works